# How to build a jQuery lightbox that can display a carousel and custom content inside

Tags: jquery, html, lightbox

I am in search for a jQuery lightbox which can display custom HTML5 content and an image carousel inside the lightbox. I searched on web but not finding any ready-made solution.

Comment: http://www.pixelzdesign.com/blog_view.php?id=55

Comment: did you really use google? There are tons of ready-made scripts out there that do exactly what you want. It might not say 'HTML 5' in the description, but just 'HTML' or 'Ajax'.. you can put whatever you want inside

Comment: Hi all, thanks a lot for your response :)

Comment: Can be closed based on the official close reason: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._

Answer (score 1):

Another one would be [GALLERIA](http://galleria.io/).

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want to display the gallery inside the lightbox like [this](http://www.realestate.com.au/property-house-nsw-chatswood-110664113).The Pretty photo is useful for your need [Demo for Preety Photo](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/)